# How come I can't ping a computer on the same network?

Tags: macos, networking, mac, macbook, ping

I use a MacBook Pro (Retina), and using my old MacBook Pro, I can ping my MacBook Pro (Retina) successfully. And I can also ping my MacBook Pro from my MacBook Pro (Retina) successfully (all in the same network).

However, I can’t seem to be able to ping a Macbook Air which is also on the same network (the MacBook Pro’s firewall is configured to *not* block ICMP and ping requests). Is it because the MacBook Air is configured differently or is it because of something else, and how can I fix this?

Comment: @JakeGould I checked, it isn't

Comment: Two accounts have asked this question, 2 hours apart: http://superuser.com/questions/883992/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Macbook Air (not the pro) has stealth mode enabled. Quoting from [Apple website](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642):

> Enabling stealth mode prevents the computer from responding to probing
>   requests. The computer still answers incoming requests for authorized
>   apps. Unexpected requests, **such as ICMP (ping)** are ignored.

Comment: Stealth mode isn't activated either.

Comment: @toggaF what are the IPs of the respective machines? Maybe they are on different subnets and the router does not allow them to talk to one another (VLANs)?